# EMR Serverless Read From S3 Cross Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, amazon-vpc

I have an EMR Application that runs inside a VPC in a Private Subnet with NAT on.
This application **can** read files from the buckets in the **same** account, but when it tries to read a file in a bucket in other aws account it gets **access denied**.

The emr applications has the following policy:

```json
S3FullAccess:
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:*",
                    "s3-object-lambda:*"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

EMR Spark packages settings:

```
--conf spark.jars.packages=org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0
```

Job Spark:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (SparkSession.builder
             .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload", True)
             .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
             .config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true")
             .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0")
             .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
             )

df_from_another_s3_account_bucket = spark.read.parquet('s3a://bucket_account_b/path/file.parquet')
```

This execution is returning the error:

```
 java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://bucket_account_b/path/file.parquet: getFileStatus on  s3a://bucket_account_b/path/file.parquet: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden;
```

I have tried using credentials in the spark configs:

```py
.config("fs.s3a.access.key", key_bucket_account_b)
.config("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_bucket_account_b)
```

I have also tried creating a bucket policy allowing the emr aws account, but still got the same error.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1543283",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1412820423",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::emr_aws_account:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_account_b"
        }
    ]
}
```

What else could I try?

Comment: Pease see cross account s3 access https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

Comment: This for EMR Serverless, not EMR on EC2 correct? If so, cross-account is supported but not documented yet. In the meantime, you should be able to follow the ERM on EKS guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/security-cross-account.html and make sure you use spark.emr-serverless instead of spark.kubernetes

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the hadoop-aws jar - that's included with EMR Serverless.